# Netcat -e on Mac OS X

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm a newbie macuser coming from Debian, and I'm a big command line user.
One one my preferred one is netcat (aka nc on mac). I especially loved the -e option which enabled to create a process that deals bidirectionnally with the strems.

Unfortunately, when I use the classic:

```
nc -l -p 6666 -e /bin/bash
```

Netcat does not agree with me, and I get this:

```
nc: illegal option -- e
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrtUuvz] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
      [-s source_ip_address] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
```

What does that mean? Can I use this command in another way?

Thanks for your help,

Rob

PS: if someone can edit the tags, would be better -- netcat, nc are not known here :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears that the `netcat` distributed in MacOS is a rather old (imported at 2005-10-07) version of netcat-openbsd clone. Here is the header file from the [netcat.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/netcat/netcat-7/netcat.c) hosted at [opensource.apple.com](https://opensource.apple.com/).

`/* $OpenBSD: netcat.c,v 1.82 2005/07/24 09:33:56 marius Exp $ */`

There are three popular versions of `netcat` in the wild:

- [gnu-netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) or netcat ver. 0.71
- [netcat 1.10](https://nc110.sourceforge.io/) or nc110 (also known as netcat-traditional in debian)
- and the [openbsd](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/) version (netcat-openbsd, the netcat metapackage points to it) which is in active development.

Currently only the gnu and 1.10 versions support `-e` option and it's considered insecure. In the 1.10 version you should compile with `-DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE` define to enable the `-e` switch.

The easiest way to install this version would be to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or other ports system (homebrew uses netcat 0.71 source).

Answer (score 3):

I've just checked the man page.  Doesn't look like that flag is supported.  I suppose you could download a different version.. (perhaps 'netcat' instead of 'nc').

Comment: Yep... I'm wondering if macports/darwin or something like that could be helpful in this case... When I'll get a little bit more time, i'll have a look at the source version. Thx for the retagging btw :)

Comment: @Rob or [`brew install netcat`](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) (← there's a link hidden in the code) :-)

Comment: @koiyu Looks good... I didn't know all this Mac things. This one sounds reassuring :)

Comment: That's perfect... If you create an answer, I'm gonna accept it! Thanks Harv as well.

Comment: @Rob: @mspasov's recent answer is more thorough than mine could be, so it deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you install Nmap (debianports) you will also get ncat.
ncat is basically an advanced version of nc with the options like:
-e, --ssl, --broker, --chat, ...

Comment: This was the solution to *all* my netcat problems on MacOS (so far) :)